# ASP.Net MVC Special Route - IgnoreRoute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to understand how the routing engine works so I put a break to inspect the `routes` variable. Since we only have one `.MapRoute` I expected 1 route to exist but I found 2. I discovered the `IgnoreRoute` has added a special route to the collection.

[image]

```
1. {System.Web.Mvc.RouteCollectionExtensions.IgnoreRouteInternal} and
2. {System.Web.Routing.Route}
```

I wanted to inspect the properties of `IgnoreRouteInternal` class just like the `Route` class but it's like that class does not exist. Typing `System.Web.Routing` and pressing dot, I could see the `Route` class but not doing the same for `System.Web.Mvc.RouteCollectionExtensions` the `IgnoreRouteInternal` could not be found in the dropdown.

What special class is the `IgnoreRouteInternal`? and where is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a internal class to MVC. It is not public to other assemblies.

Actually its a private class inside of RouteCollectionExtensions, which has the same effect as an internal class.

You can view its source on [codeplex](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/1ccfcdfc11da#src/System.Web.Mvc/RouteCollectionExtensions.cs).

Comment: I guessed as much but shouldn't it show in the `RouteCollectionExtensions` class. I inspect the source of that class, there is no `IgnoreRouteInternal` in it. Is that normal?

Comment: @codingbiz - how did you inspect the source? - its at the bottom of the file i linked to.

Comment: In visual studio object browser of course. I could see the class as `private sealed` in codeplex

Comment: the object browser won't show you those. btw, object browser doesnt show source code.